# views replacing ul li within a large block of html text

Tags: views, 6

I have a odd issue.  I am using Views 3 and Drupal 6, when I create content with ul and li tags, Views strips out the list tags and replaces them with the following:

```
nbsp;
     .nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;content
     .nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;content
     .nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;content
     .nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;content
nbsp;
```

instead of:

```
<ul>
      <li>content</li>
      <li>content</li>
      <li>content</li>
      <li>content</li>
</ul>
```

The content appears correctly in the database, but in display and preview from Views the rewrite happens.

I have the following options:
add default classes
  rewrite output (this was the first thing I checked and is displaying this behavior regardless of this rewrite)
hide contents if empty.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing the [Theme developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module and tracking down the template that might be rendering that output.